# How can I monitor the status of a variable in Angular 2 when using routing?

Tags: angular, routes

I am working on an Angular 2 project where the user can navigate from tab to tab (via routing).
On one of these tabs, there's a section that is collapsible. According to a boolean variable (false by default), this section is hidden (by default) or displayed. But at the moment, if the user opens this section, navigates away from this tab where the is located and comes back again to that same tab, the section is hidden again.
I would like the user to find the section in the state it was when she/he left it. What would be a good approach please to make this possible ? I tried using a service thinking it would keep the status of my variable unchanged, but it didn't work as expected.
The expected behaviour is for the user to open a collapsible section from a tab, move to another tab, come back to the first tab and still have the collapsible section open. At the moment, when coming back to the first tab, the collapsible section returns to the status it's been instantiated with, the section is closed.
Thank you.

From the `.component.html` file here is the button to toggle the collapsible section:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" (click)="toggleShowSideMenu()" type="checkbox" id="productList">
    <i [ngClass]="sideMenuIsShown ? 'fa fa-minus-square':'fa fa-plus-square'"></i>
    Products list
  </button>
</div>
```

From the `.component.ts` file:

```
// The side menu is hidden by default
  sideMenuIsShown: boolean = false;

// Defines the status of the side section upon the launch of the application
  ngOnInit() {
    this.linearProductsService.productListStatus.subscribe(
      (sideMenuStatus: boolean) => {
        this.sideMenuIsShown = sideMenuStatus;
      }
    )
  }

// Toggle feature to handle the side menu for the products list
  toggleShowSideMenu() {
    this.linearProductsService.productListStatus.emit(!this.sideMenuIsShown);
  }
```

From the `.service.ts` file;

```
// Emitter to determine the status of the variable defining whether the side menu is visible or hidden
productListStatus = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Comment: Thank you very much JoSSte for your prompt feedback unfortunately this solution does not achieve my goal, most likely because my description wasn't clear enough. Basically on one page of the app with this URL: "localhost:4200/a" there is a section that can be hidden/displayed. When the user unhides this section and click on another tab opening a new URL: "localhost:4200/b" and then revert to the first URL, "localhost:4200/a", the section is hidden again while I would like to keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use observables**.

In your service

```
private readonly productListStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(
    false
  );
productListStatus$ = this.productListStatus.asObservable();

setProductListStatus(newStatus: boolean) :void {
this.productListStatus.next(newStatus);
}
```

Then in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.linearProductsService.productListStatus$.subscribe(
    (sideMenuStatus: boolean) => {
      this.sideMenuIsShown = sideMenuStatus;
    }
  )
}

toggleShowSideMenu() {
  this.linearProductsService.setProductListStatus(!this.sideMenuIsShown);
}
```

Thats it!

emember manage unsubscription from observables to improve performance.